# RelativeLayout problem. ImageView scroll up when keyboard shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, adview

I'm trying to show a ImageView under a AdView like image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eyCF.png). The problem is where the EditText is active, the keyboard is shown and if the AdView is loaded, all works perfect, but when the AdView isn't loaded, the ImageView scroll up out of the screen like image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwLhb.png)

Here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="top">

<com.google.ads.AdView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXX" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/frame008" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="50dip"></ImageView>
```

The EditText and Submit button:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button android:text="Submit" android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="submit" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your time!!

[image: When ads doesn't load.]

[image: When ads loads]

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below should be what you need to position the views as you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout4">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, the problem stills exists. The image appears center vertical so when it scroll up, is more visible, but a part of pic stills invisible...